# Is it possible to add a header to a mandrill webhook for inbound emails?

Tags: mandrill

In the inbound emails second, it said in the docs that when an email is received, it will forward the email through a POST request, so I should have an endpoint that will receive these POST requests. The thing is, we want the POST request sent by mandrill to have specific header values, possibly a token to verify it's from mandrill. Otherwise, I think anyone will be able spam us with fake POST requests. Is it possible to add a custom header?

Comment: Couldn't this hypothetical person just add the header also & pretend to be from mandrill !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not currently possible to add a custom header for POSTs. Mandrill, does, however, offer [webhook authentication](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/23704122-Authenticating-webhook-requests) so you know it's coming from Mandrill and hasn't been modified.